# How do I apply an effect to the entire result of multiple stacked clips in FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, effects

How can apply an effect to the RESULT of multiple composited clips in Final Cut Pro X? Googling all I see is how to apply the same effect to multiple clips but that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to apply a single effect to the result of compositing multiple clips.

For example, one way would be to render my video without effects. Then start a new project, load the rendered video, apply the effect. It seems like I shouldn't have to render the video and start an entire new project to achieve this.

To give a simple example. Start a new project. Make the project 1280x720p, drop in a iPhone portrait mode video (make sure the project stays 1280x720p), apply the colorize event. Since the colorize event only applies to the clip I get this

[image]

But I want it to apply to the entire video (the result of all the clips)

[image]

Note I am not try to achieve the effect shown above. I just needed to throw together an example showing the issue (effect applies to clip instead of to entire video).

Is there a way to do it short of rendering out the entire video, starting a new project and applying the effects to the rendered video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not entirely sure what you explain. However I try. 
Did you look into the option of an adjustment layer?
http://www.fcp.co/final-cut-pro/tutorials/945-how-to-build-and-use-adjustment-layers-in-final-cut-pro-x

Comment: That would work. I guess I need to go buy Motion though.

Comment: Someone posted a already created Adjustment Layer from Motion [here](http://www.fcpxbook.com/tips/adjustment-layer.html)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your timeline so I'm not sure if this might help too:

I think you can select all clips within the timeline and than group them (alt + g) to a compound clip. This way you can add effects onto the compound layer and it will be placed on all.